# R Dplyr and string values, how to split and get the second element? vapply/sapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

Been having difficulty with this one data frame manipulation in R. 
I have two columns for well height and a date-time string ("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss").

I would like to extract all the rows from this table that occur at midnight (00:00:00).

I could manipulate this table in seconds with python, but I want to figure it out in R **using strsplit()** instead of POSIXct.

**How do I mutate the table so that I split the date-time string and extract just the time value into a new column?**

I think the answer is in vapply, but I have been drenching myself in manuals the last couple weeks and still can't figure it out.

Comment: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks**. For statistics questions, use stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. it can be done in multiple ways. Try this:

```r
## some data
df <- data.frame(height=c(11,12),time = c("1999-9-9 00:00:00","1999-9-9 00:00:02"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
#>   height              time
#> 1     11 1999-9-9 00:00:00
#> 2     12 1999-9-9 00:00:02

## In base R

df2<- df
df2$hms <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(df2$time," "))[,2]
df2[df2$hms=="00:00:00",]
#>   height              time      hms
#> 1     11 1999-9-9 00:00:00 00:00:00

## In tidyverse

library(dplyr)
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(hms = gsub(".*(..:..:..).*","\\1",time)) %>%
  filter(hms == "00:00:00")

df3
#>   height              time      hms
#> 1     11 1999-9-9 00:00:00 00:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: `which` is not needed in your base solution.

Comment: @AndreElrico thanks, you are correct. I tested and it's 2 times faster without` which`.

Comment: Thanks all, the base R example is what I was trying to get at. The Both Andre and TC were excellent in understanding what I meant. Gsub() was a clever trick using dplyr though I much prefer regex's, so I appreciate the sub() example.

Comment: On second glance, both can accept regular expressions as the pattern. escaped escape characters tricked me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide an example, so here is my guess:

Let's say you have a character vector (could be a column):

```
dateTimes <- c("1999-01-01 11:11:11", "1999-01-01 12:12:12", "1999-01-01 13:13:13")
```

You extract the times in the end:

```
ans <- sub(".*-\\d+\\s", "", dateTimes, perl = T)
#[1] "11:11:11" "12:12:12" "13:13:13"
```

Save them into a new variable or column:

When you want to extract rows that occur at `00:00:00` simply use a string comparison and subset your data:

```
df1[ans == "00:00:00",]
```